# How to keep Lua bindings from cluttering up C++ code?

Tags: c++, scripting, lua

I'm writing a game engine that uses C++ and Lua (and Luabind).

Currently, I'm writing all the bindings inside the constructor of the class being binded. I really don't like this because it's cluttering up my code.

Where should I put the Lua glue code so that it is out of the way and not cluttering up my codebase?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method I have used with good results is to give each class that needs Lua bindings a static class method with the following signature:

```
static luabind::scope luaBindings();
```

The definition of this method looks like this:

```
luabind::scope
MyClass::luaBindings() {
    using namespace luabind;
    return class_<MyClass>("MyClass")
        .def(constructor<>())
        .def("someMethod", &MyClass::someMethod)
    ;
}
```

Then, in some other place, I initialize the Lua state like this:

```
void
initializeLua(
    lua_State* L
) {
    luabind::open(L);
    luabind::module(L) [
        MyClass::luaBindings(),
        MyOtherClass::luaBindings()
    ];
}
```

This way, all Lua bindings are contained in the static class methods. The Lua state is initialized in a very controlled way, without headaches about the order that classes are exported in.

The only downside I have encountered so far is that the `initializeLua` function needs to know all the classes being exported. Depending on the number of classes, this will result in a rather large list of included files and potentially long compilation times. If that's an issue for you, you can build the `luabind::scope` hierarchically like this:

```
luabind::scope
moduleABindings() {
    return (
        MyClass::luaBindings(),
        MyOtherClass::luaBindings()
    );
}

luabind::scope
moduleBBindings() {
    return (
         Foo::luaBindings(),
         Bar::luaBindings()
    );
}

void
initializeLua(
    lua_State* L
) {
    luabind::open(L);
    luabind::module(L) [
        moduleABindings(),
        moduleBBindings()
    ];
}
```

By separating those functions into separate compilation units, a small change in one of the exported classes' headers will not require recompiling the whole initializer, just the module that has changed.

Comment: This is neat. Could you briefly explain what this is/does? `class_<MyClass>("MyClass")
        .def(constructor<>())
        .def("someMethod", &MyClass::someMethod)` I'm having trouble understanding it.

Comment: @StevenLu That line exports the `MyClass` class with an empty constructor to the Lua scripting engine followed by defining a method `someMethod` on Lua's `MyClass` definition and that method call invokes the C++ method `MyClass::someMethod`.

Comment: Is `constructor<>` a type defined by Lua's C++ API? Last I played with Lua it had no C++ stuff. **edit:** Ah, I recognize it now. It's Luabind!

Answer (score 4):

0) Move your constructor to a separate file, there's no rule that says your entire class has to be all in one physical .cpp file.

1) Put your binding code in a separate function in a different file, have the constructor call it?  This would be the preferred method.

2) write your binding code in a separate file, inline, and #include it directly into your constructor.  This is an oldschool way to get around, not so great these days.

```
fn::fn()
{
#include "clutter.txt"
}
```

At least that way it's only cluttering up your project and not the code you see on a daily basis.

Comment: There's no reason it _has_ to be in the constructor for the object.  I just put it there because it was the simplest place to put it. I'd rather have it out of the class entirely.